# $.each function to replace to for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
validateScaledIntegerNumberGridFields: function(frm) {
            var fields = $('.scaledInteger', frm);
            var result = true;
            for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
                var scale = $(fields[i]).data("scale");
                var separator = $(fields[i]).data("separator");
                var decimalOnly = new RegExp('^[0-9]\\d*                                 
                              (\\'+separator+'\\d{'+scale+','+scale+'})?$');
          if(fields[i].value != "" && !(fields[i].value).match(decimalOnly)) {
                    $(fields[i]).addClass('form-attr-error');
                    result = false;
          }
          else {
               $(fields[i]).removeClass('form-attr-error');
          }
       }
            return result;
        }
```

I need help here to convert for loop to $.each function and after convert to .each how can i get 'i' value. Please help me on this.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not require `i` most probably as I don't see any useful purpose of `i` except to access the `fields` array.

Each `element` that matches the selector could be iterated using `each()`. Here `this`references the current element that is iterated. You could also obtain the value of `i` from the argument of the callback function.

```js
function validateScaledIntegerNumberGridFields(frm) {            
            var result = true;
            $('.scaledInteger', frm).each(function(i){
                var scale = $(this).data("scale");
                var separator = $(this).data("separator");
                var decimalOnly = new RegExp('^[0-9]\\d*(\\'+separator+'\\d{'+scale+','+scale+'})?$');
          if(this.value != "" && !(this.value).match(decimalOnly)) {
                    $(this).addClass('form-attr-error');
                    result = false;
          }
          else {
               $(this).removeClass('form-attr-error');
          }
       });       
            return result;
        }

validateScaledIntegerNumberGridFields()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: $.each() and each() are different.

each() Ref:https://api.jquery.com/each/

$.each() Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/